# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /.../Compiler.php on line 4503 in Opencart 2.3

Tags: php, opencart, php-7.2

I get this message on a theme that I am using with my opencart 2.3.0.2: Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /.../Compiler.php on line 4503.

This is what is writen on that line in that php file:

```
        $color = $this->assertColor($args[0]);
        $amount = Util::checkRange('amount', new Range(0, 100), $args[1], '%');

        return $this->adjustHsl($color, 3, -$amount);                       (<= line 4503)
    }
```

I think it has to do with the PHP version, which is set at 7.2 (can't set it to older versions)...
Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm going to guess that `$amount` is not a number. Check the value by logging it or dumping it

Comment: Perhaps the theme doesn't support PHP7 properly. Is it old? Your opencart version is quite old.

Comment: `var_dump($amount)`  probably adding a `%` and then you try to make it negative with `-`.